How to add settings.xml file to azure variables?
I'm working with a Maven task in Azure DevOps, and I need to refer to a settings.xml file. I previously added the settings.xml as a variable in the library, but since I locked the variable, it has become a secret, and I can't access it anymore.
How can I add the settings.xml back as a variable to the library for another pipeline, and use it in the Maven task below?
  - task: Maven@4
displayName: maven package
inputs:
  mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
  goals: 'clean install spring-boot:repackage'
  options: '-Dmaven.test.skip=true -U'
  publishJUnitResults: false
  javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
  jdkVersionOption: '1.17'
  mavenVersionOption: 'Default'
  mavenAuthenticateFeed: true
  effectivePomSkip: true
  sonarQubeRunAnalysis: $(isStage)
  sqMavenPluginVersionChoice: 'latest'
  settingsXml: $(MAVEN_SETTINGS_XML)


You cannot retrieve the correspondent variable from a variable group (library) using the portal because it is set as a secret, but you can reuse in more than one pipeline.

Since the variable is a secret variable in Azure Pipeline, it cannot be displayed directly in the pipeline.
If you are defining the variable in Library -> Variable Groups, you can directly use the variable group in another Pipeline. Refer to this doc: Link a variable group to a pipeline
For example:
variables:
- group: vargroup

steps:
- task: Maven@4
  displayName: maven package
  inputs:
    mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
    goals: 'clean install spring-boot:repackage'
    options: '-Dmaven.test.skip=true -U'
    publishJUnitResults: false
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '1.17'
    mavenVersionOption: 'Default'
    mavenAuthenticateFeed: true
    effectivePomSkip: true
    sonarQubeRunAnalysis: $(isStage)
    sqMavenPluginVersionChoice: 'latest'
    settingsXml: $(MAVEN_SETTINGS_XML)

On the other hand, if you need to get the value of the secret variable, you can display specific values by outputting it to a file.
Here is an example: You can add PowerShell task to output the value to txt file, then you can use Publish Build Artifacts task to publish the file in Pipeline.
variables:
- group: vargroup

steps:
- powershell: |
    $env:MAPVALUE | Out-File $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\settings.txt

  env:
    MAPVALUE: $(varname)
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\settings.txt'
    ArtifactName: 'settingsfile'
    publishLocation: 'Container'

Then you can get the secret variable value in Pipeline artifacts.
For example:

In this case, you can also manually add the Pipeline variable with the actual value to another Pipeline.
